# wordpress check if current page is the only grand child

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to do a statement that checks whether the current page is the only `grand child page` in wordpress and cannot seem to wrap my head around it.

ie 2 levels deep

parent > child > grandchild

if there is more than 1 grandchild page, perform action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$siblings = get_posts(array(
    'exclude'     => array($post->ID),
    'post_type'   => $post->post_type,
    'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
    'numberposts' => 1 // we're only checking if there ARE siblings, so save a little memory
));

$is_only_child = empty($siblings);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I just echoed the result and it does not seem to echo anything if($is_only_child) { echo 'yes'; }

Comment: Where are you using this code? Is the `$post` global available? What happens if you `print_r( $siblings )`?